# Creating a new entity, and updating another at once

Tags: datetime, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I've searched a lot about this, and seriously asking is my last resource, doctrine is kicking me hard.

I have an entity named "Contract" and another "Request", a Contract may have several Requests, when adding a new Request I search for an existent contract of that client and associate it if already exists or create it if not.

In RequestRepository.php:

```
 public function findOrCreate($phone)
  {
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $contract = $this->findOneBy(array('phone' => $phone));

    if($contract === null)
    {
        $contract = new Contract();
        $contract->setPhone($phone)
                 ->setDesDate(new \DateTime());

        # save only if new
        $em->persist($contract);
    }

    return $contract;
 }
```

The thing is, when the contract is new it works ok, but when is "reused" from db I can't modify its attributes. I checked the OneToMany and ManyToOne already.

In Contract.php:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Request", mappedBy="contract")
 */
private $id;
```

In Request.php:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cid\FrontBundle\Entity\Contract", inversedBy="id", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $contract;
```

I also have a method which modifies an attribute within Contract.php:

```
 public function addTime($months)
{
    $days = $months * 30;

    $this->des_date->add(new \DateInterval("P".$days."D"));

    return $this;
}
```

I create the request and "findOrCreate" a contract, but if the later is not "fresh" the addTime does not save to db.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The controller is a common CRUD with minor modifications.

Don't worry about "request" name clash, the actual code is in spanish, Request = Solicitud

```
public function createAction(Request $req) 
 {
    $entity  = new Request();
    $form = $this->createForm(new RequestType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($req);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity->setUser($this->getUser()); 

        $data = $request->request->get('cid_frontbundle_requesttype');
        $phone = $data['phone_number'];

        $reqRep = $em->getRepository('FrontBundle:Request');

        $entity = $reqRep->newRequest($entity, $phone);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('request_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('FrontBundle:Request:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The newRequest:

```
public function newRequest($request, $phone)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $contractRep = $em->getRepository('FrontBundle:Contract');
    $contract = $contractRep->findOrCreate($phone);

    $contract->addTime(123); # this is the problem, I use var_dump and this method works, but doesn't persists

    $em->persist($request);
    $em->flush();

    return $request;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your controller code?

Comment: Done, I already tried N+1 ways, everything works ok execpt the persist() of the contract when it's already in the database. Is like if doctrine were ignoring the update.

Comment: The controller code you've posted is the on for the creation, the one that works, right?

Comment: Can you post the one that doesn't work? :)

Comment: Sorry, done, that newRequest method is where lies the issue, that addTime call is working "in memory" but when persisting doctrine ignores it.

Comment: You call `$em->persist($solicitud);` when you want to persist `$contract`, no? So it would be `$em->persist($contract);` instead. Or does `$solicitud` come from somewhere else?

Comment: @cheesemacfly solicitud is the spanish word for request, sorry forgot to translate. ;) There's no difference if I call persist on contract also, it doesn't works if it is already on db.

Comment: I think I'm onto something, does the fact that I do the update on the object "on the fly" affects doctrine's behavior in some way? I mean all I do in addTime is $this->des_date->add(new \DateInterval("P".$days."D"));, so the des_date object (DateTime) is not destroyed just updated.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand why you call `$em->persist($request);` when `$des_date` has been modified on the `$contract` object. You don't modify the `$request` object in your `newRequest()` function.

Comment: @cheesemacfly yes I do, that code you see is the simplified version. Request has more attributes which are being filled right there. Sorry for the trimming, just trying to make it more readable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25558/discussion-between-cheesemacfly-and-dhunter)

Comment: @cheesemacfly sorry, my company doesn't allow me to engage in any form of online chat, even if it is for job purposes. C'est la vie :( Anyway I think I got it, let me try one thing and I'll post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka!! The issue was that doctrine seems to check the objects by reference, and all I did with the contract was adding a DateInterval to a DateTime property, so the object was the same for doctrine's matter and there was no saving. This is the code that made it.

```
public function addTime($months)
{
    $days = $months * 30; # I know DateInterval has months but this is company policy ;)

    $other = new \DateTime($this->des_date->format('Y-m-d')); # creating a brand new DateTime did the trick

    $other->add(new \DateInterval("P".$days."D"));
    $this->des_date = $other;

    return $this;
}
```

Thanks for everything @cheesemacfly.